# Java Killing Popup Process

Tags: java, process, monitor, kill

I'm now writing a simple program to simulate real user surfing web. However, if there is any popup or program pop up on the screen, I need to either minimize or close it to prevent it from interacting with the wrong program. So I have to monitor the running process or detect for new process? I tried using Javascript but it requires ActiveX in IE and quite problematic. Can someone kindly advise me on how to start on writing that part of the code? I googled for a bit and it says those process window.opener.close() or Process.Destroy() commands. Thanks. Below is a simple draft of my code.

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaApplication1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);
            if (n == 1)
            {
                String myURL = "www.facebook.com";
                java.awt.Desktop myNewBrowserDesktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                java.net.URI myNewLocation = new java.net.URI(myURL);
                myNewBrowserDesktop.browse(myNewLocation);
            }
            if (n == 2)
            {
                String myURL = "www.google.com";
                java.awt.Desktop myNewBrowserDesktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                java.net.URI myNewLocation = new java.net.URI(myURL);
                myNewBrowserDesktop.browse(myNewLocation);
            }
            if (n == 3)
            {
                String myURL = "www.yahoo.com";
                java.awt.Desktop myNewBrowserDesktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                java.net.URI myNewLocation = new java.net.URI(myURL);
                myNewBrowserDesktop.browse(myNewLocation);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. `Desktop.browse` [Launches the default browser to display the URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29). The content of the document (html) that browser displays may cause the browser to open a new window or do anything else that a browser might do when you browse that URI manually in your browser.

In most cases, the browser will not create a new process. Irrespective of whether it creates a new process or only a window, it will not provide any notification to your calling program; so your calling program has no way of controlling those windows.

You may be able to do something like this by using an embedded browser.

Comment: Thanks, what if i try to make iexplore.exe process (IE8 in my case) to always "Bring to Front" and override all possible popup programs and put it in a infinite for loop in Java?

Comment: How do you "verride all possible popup programs"? What does the infinite loop have to with this?

Comment: Because the simulating web surfing session will take place for a long time so in order to ensure no popup program interfering with the browser I have to use infinite loop to continuously check.

Comment: But what will you check in the infinite loop? This is making no sense.

Comment: Sorry should be continuously focusing on the main window(browser).
I came up with these codes.
for(;;)
        {
        JFrame component = new JFrame();
        Component compFocusOwner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
        Window windowFocusOwner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusedWindow();
        boolean b = component.isFocusOwner();
        }

Comment: You might be able to bring the browser window in focus and top (unless the user kills it) but you won't be able so suppress the pop-ups.